# Is $V/m$ equal to $N/C$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, si-units

Is $V/m$ equal to $N/C$? I searched a lot but I can't find it anywhere

V=Volt

m=meters

N=Newton

C=Coulomb

Comment: [Searched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt#Definition)?

Comment: Before asking a question like this you should reduce things to basic SI units. 1 V = 1 J/C = 1 N.m/C. You can do the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Newtons per Coulomb is force per unit charge--which is electric field strength, which is also the derivative of electric potential: Volts per meter.

Answer (score 1):

1 Coulomb is 1 $As$.  1 Newton is 1 $kgms^{-2}$.  1 Volt is $kgm^2s^{-3}A^{-1}$.

$\frac{V}{M}=kgms^{-3}A^{-1}$.

$\frac{N}{C}=kgms^{-3}A^{-1}$.

They have the same SI units.

Comment: Please accept my answer